# How to handle swiped item on PagedList data source Recycler view

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm working with PagedListAdapter and observing data okay now. How do I handle onSwiped item using ItemTouchHelper on RecyclerView item.

Since I am using PagedListAdapter I cant get list of items and handle remove/inserts.

```
ItemViewModel.ItemPagedList.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<PagedList<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<Item> items) {




                itemsAdapter.submitList(items);

            }
        });
```

I expect to remove and insert items when swiped on from the recycler view.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I came across this: https://www.nplix.com/paging-library-architecture-components/